# Too much screen updates over remote desktop connection

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, remote-desktop

I ran into a very weird problem. I have a VB.NET program which calls another program which runs in the background. We're using a special software here to deliver this software over web. What this software basically does is, that i creates a new remote desktop connection, grabs the screen and opens up a web server.

While running the sub programm / sub process the screen does not react smooth anymore, it gets very low and then freezes. We figured out, that we're triggering too many screen updates at once so that we simply flood our connection which causes the crash in the browser.

Is there any simple way to determine how many screen updates were sent and which causes these updates? Best would be that we can identify the process so that we can investigate further.

The whole process is ran as a `backgroundWorker` which then creates another process.

Edit:

Could it have something to do with the CPU load (which is very high)? Although the subprocess is executed in the background - and is visible in the process list - is there any chance that this causes the UI Update?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. It was a `Timer` updating the View every microsecond becuase the `Interval` was not correctly set.